# Keras early stopping callback does not recognise 'start_from_epoch' argument

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback

For some reason the start_from_epoch argument in the EarlyStopping callback is not recognised.

```
import tensorflow as tf

cbk = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                       min_delta=0,
                                       patience=3,
                                       restore_best_weights = True,
                                       start_from_epoch=10
                                       )]

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start_from_epoch'
```

even though it's clearly listed as an argument in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping)

I have recent versions of TensorFlow installed, so anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using older version of `Tensorflow` Try this

`!pip install -q tensorflow==2.11.0`

```
    monitor='val_loss',
    min_delta=0,
    patience=0,
    verbose=0,
    mode='auto',
    baseline=None,
    restore_best_weights=False,
    start_from_epoch=0
)
```